# Typescript "in" operator fails to work in nested interface

Tags: typescript, nested, typing

I have the following dumbed down example ([link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QMpjpAFQgzGQG8AoZZAI0wiJIC5kAiYU4DZOW+5EgHsoKDhAC2rANwUAvhQqhIsRClzDijUpWoIArkPEBGFjurIYgwaarnqdKCxB7xNaDLuyPyL7aEiASUhjGztxOFAWdCxcfAZiMG9qLARBEAATOCgATyj6WMIE719ksA0giQAmUPNw0Gq0fLxCkiSBCFSMrOyG6Jxm+NbbX3kKTpIBMpESBJZ1aa1kAF5yW31DE1W7S2stuz5HZABOI4AaW2pZc8vryfLgzbNqOpBTPiwtFnZObl46LDuImQYkkPluyQ6aUyOTe-0GYC+HGBv3eKH8omCrDBw1u6Iq4gaT2QL0JqM+bCRXB4qMBGIkWKuF3anWhPVh9HJ32R1LhtOBmOxNzkMgoMD0IAQYGAaWQkBIBAwAB4CEZkBAAB6QDLcADWEGyghgyHmmgSAD4ABS2OVgBUAQSgAHMWCrbp1IJqWHqDUaTRgtABtFUAXQoAEo9uNSPooFB8ctaTMSAGbfancGRbo0hMY1AAMJpD0QdLxla5-EB90asAZ2zAI0W1hwrRY0DIXMF8Aa4v4iNEgD0-eBIGQAAtoBiBKPBHoADbpWgoXhgbIABxQYFH+DVmog2tl48aMQGiyU0HgSCZ40Es4gADpZ4JHRaO4XuyXgmG2tfbw+ny+9FjTsiw-CQ72bBIv2QQdkAAUQAJXggB5eDhlsEQwEAkdXy7dUe2CGR5CjZAMKwgA1OBZwTVMMEbPFgkqVhTjYElWC-MZsxve9H2fUioBACjZ3AjlIKkaCh03KkqUEHVmLcBA4AMFACGwZAdRAQQAHduE00dgAQUd+QkfluQ1RAwFnbIKCAA)):

```
interface BaseStateTest {
  baseTest: "it is a base store item";
}

interface StoresTest {
  custom1: {
    foo: {
      bar: number;
    };
  };
  storeItem1: {
    main: BaseStateTest;
    secondary: BaseStateTest;
  };
  storeItem2: {
    main2: BaseStateTest;
    secondary2: BaseStateTest;
  };
}

const storestest: StoresTest = {
  custom1: {
    foo: {
      bar: 99,
    },
  },
  storeItem1: {
    main: { baseTest: "it is a base store item" },
    secondary: { baseTest: "it is a base store item" },
  },
  storeItem2: {
    main2: { baseTest: "it is a base store item" },
    secondary2: { baseTest: "it is a base store item" },
  },
};

function testTs<T1 extends keyof StoresTest>(
  testTsArg: T1,
  context: keyof StoresTest[T1]
) {
  const currItem = storestest[testTsArg];

  const currContexedItem = currItem[context];
  if ("baseTest" in currContexedItem) {
    // in here it should be a type that extends the BaseStateTest interface
    console.log(currContexedItem);
    console.log(currContexedItem.baseTest); // ERROR
  }
  return currContexedItem;
}
const returnVal = testTs("storeItem2", "main2");
console.log(returnVal.baseTest); // this is ok, because TS knows which item it is exactly
```

I'm curious on how I can get TypeScript type inference to work on the line where I want to log:

`console.log(currContexedItem.baseTest); // ERROR`

My goal is to identify the type of a deeply nested object using the TypeScript `in` operator.

Unfortunately I cannot seem to be able to accomplish it without changing the data structure to a less nested state. I am greeted with a TS error instead:

```
Property 'baseTest' does not exist on type '{ abc: number; abc2: { test: number; }; storeItem1: { main: BaseStateTest; secondary: BaseStateTest; }; storeItem2: { main2: BaseStateTest; secondary2: BaseStateTest; }; }[T1][keyof { ...; }[T1]]'.(2339)
```

Is there any existing solution that allows me to identify the type inside a function of such a nested object **without** changing the data structure?

Comment: Could you modify this example to be a [mre] without extraneous issues?  The code here would explode at runtime with a number of different inputs, like `const returnVal = testTs("abc2", "test")`, which ends up using the `in` operator on a primitive.  Maybe you can make it so that no primitives appear until three or so levels deep?

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to get the compiler to reason particularly well about such deeply nested types that depend on unspecified generic type parameters.  You can manually calculate the type as a union, but the compiler won't see that `currContextdItem` is assignable to that type.  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mZr8Em).

Comment: @jcalz Sure, I simplified the example a little. Thanks for the suggestion. Union type casting is already quit helpful for me, though I would of course prefer a more robust approach. Thanks!